# How to set Left Click only in TreeSelectionEvent

Tags: java, swing, click, jtree

I write code in jtree for method click, but i want the action only in left click

```
class SelectionListener  extends DefaultMutableTreeNode implements TreeSelectionListener {
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent se) {...}
```

Comment: don't re-mix data (== treeNode) and view/controller (== selectionListener) - separation of concern is there for a reason ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are capturing a `MouseEvent` then you can use the following method to check whether the click was a left-click:

`SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(mouseEvent)`